# Django call 'id' expected a number but got string

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-import-export

Django errors with django-import-export libraries.

I want to import data from excel to db via django admin. I use for it django-import-export, but i got Field 'id' expected a number but got 'HPI'.

[image]

Excel file contains
[image]

I found answer, that I have to add exclude = ('id',), but it didn't help. Also i did migrations, it didn't help too.
How to fix it and have ability to import 6 columns data from excel to db via django admin?

models.py

```
    from django_mysql.models import JSONField, Model
    from django.db import models



    class Category(Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

        class Meta:
            ordering = ('-id',)
            verbose_name = 'Category'
            verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'

        def __str__(self):
            return self.title


    class Tag(Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

        class Meta:
            ordering = ('-id',)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.title


    class Type(Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

        class Meta:
            ordering = ('-id',)
            verbose_name = 'Type'
            verbose_name_plural = 'Types'

        def __str__(self):
            return self.title


    class Macro(Model):
        type = models.ForeignKey(
            Type,
            max_length=100,
            null=True,
            blank=True,
            on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
        tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)
        category = models.ForeignKey(
            Category, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
        abbreviation = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
        title = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Title')
        content = models.TextField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)

        class Meta:
            ordering = ('-id',)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.title
```

admin.py

```
    from django.contrib import admin

    from import_export import resources
    from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin

    from .models import Category, Tag, Type, Macro


    class MacroResource(resources.ModelResource):

        class Meta:
            model = Macro
            skip_unchanged = True
            report_skipped = True
            exclude = ('id', )
            export_order = ('type', 'tags', 'category', 'abbreviation', 'title', 'content')


    @admin.register(Macro)
    class MacroAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
        resource_class = MacroResource
        list_display = ('id', 'type', 'tags_list', 'category', 'abbreviation', 'title', 'content')
        search_fields = ('title', 'category__title', 'type__title', 'abbreviation', 'content', )

        def tags_list(self, obj):
            tags = [t for t in obj.tags.all()]
            return ' '.join(str(tags)) if tags else '-'


    @admin.register(Category)
    class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        list_display = ('id', 'title')


    @admin.register(Tag)
    class TagAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        list_display = ('id', 'title')

        def __str__(self):
            return self.title


    @admin.register(Type)
    class TypeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        list_display = ('id', 'title')
```

Comment: BTW, how are you getting such nice error reporting out of import-export? I only get a list of stack traces.

Comment: @GregKaleka I dunno, it's just error report in admin dashboard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was with ForeignKey and ManyToMany fields of a database model. So django-import-export library need to get widgets for this fields.

More about it here: https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_widgets.html#import_export.widgets.ForeignKeyWidget

Solution: 
admin.py

```
        class MacroResource(resources.ModelResource):

            type = fields.Field(
                column_name='type',
                attribute='type',
                widget=ForeignKeyWidget(Type, 'title'))

            category = fields.Field(
                column_name='category',
                attribute='category',
                widget=ForeignKeyWidget(Category, 'title'))

            tags = fields.Field(
                column_name='tags',
                attribute='tags',
                widget=ManyToManyWidget(Tag, field='title'))

            class Meta:
                model = Macro
                skip_unchanged = True
                report_skipped = True
                exclude = ('id', )
                import_id_fields = ('title',)

                fields = ('type', 'tags', 'category', 'abbreviation', 'title', 'content')
```

instead of

```
        class MacroResource(resources.ModelResource):

            class Meta:
                model = Macro
                skip_unchanged = True
                report_skipped = True
                exclude = ('id', )
                export_order = ('type', 'tags', 'category', 'abbreviation', 'title', 'content')
```

Answer (score 1):

Django-import-export expects the first column to be `id`.

If these are new objects, simply leave the `id` column blank. Otherwise, put the database id of the object in that field.

If you're not able to modify the file, or don't want to, and you will *always* be adding new rows to the database (not modifying existing ones), you can create an id field dynamically in your resource class by overriding the method `before_import` and forcing `get_instance` to always return `False`.

```
class MacroResource(resources.ModelResource):

    def before_import(self, dataset, using_transactions, dry_run, **kwargs):
        dataset.insert_col(0, col=["",]*dataset.height, header="id")

    def get_instance(self, instance_loader, row):
        return False

    class Meta:
        model = Macro
        skip_unchanged = True
        report_skipped = True
        export_order = ('type', 'tags', 'category', 'abbreviation', 'title', 'content')
```

Comment: Thanks, but I got and error "before_import() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given". I remove dry_run and got "before_import() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given". May you help with it?

Comment: I add using_transactions to before_import() however got a similar error "Some rows failed to validate
Please correct these errors in your data where possible, then reupload it using the form above." and "Field 'id' expected a number but got 'HPI'."

Comment: Ah yes, sorry - `using_transactions` does need to be in the call signature. As for still getting the error - I think we also need to override the `get_instance` method. I updated my answer. If that doesn't work, can you dig into the stack trace and see where the error is stemming from?

Comment: Unfortunately this did not help. I don’t get an error in the console, only this "POST /admin/macros/macro/import/ HTTP/1.1" 200 15554 .I see an error message in admin dashboard such as the "Some rows failed to validate
Please correct these errors in your data where possible, then reupload it using the form above." and "TYPE
Field 'id' expected a number but got 'HPI'."

Answer (score 0):

The attributes where you are using a foreign key in the model,
you need to specify the id of the parent model and not the value in the xlsx/csv file.

Comment: can you please elaborate on how to specify id of the parent model in the attribute used in ForeignKeyWidget? It will be helpful for me. Thanks

Comment: as we know each object has a unique id(primary key). So we need to specify the id of that object instead of the name of the object.

If there are two obejcts with the same name so to avoid that error we use their primary key/unique id in the table.

Hope that it was helpful.