# Django Import Export data without ID

Tags: python, django, widget, django-import-export

I tried to export data from Django to Excel, but every thing walk behind me, when I export a Excel File, Django Export only Ids :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I247k.png)

I tried to walk behind some tutorials like :
https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_widgets.html
and
[Django call 'id' expected a number but got string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59937531/django-call-id-expected-a-number-but-got-string).

In Django App, I have:
models.py

```
from pyexpat import model
from statistics import mode
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.base import Model
from django.forms import IntegerField



class Post(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)


class Person(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"({self.name} is {self.post} "



class Room(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length= 150 )

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)


class Classification(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(auto_created=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"({self.name} Take {self.room}  at {self.date})"
```

admin.py

```
    from django.contrib import admin
    from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin
    from .models import *
    from import_export import fields, resources
    from import_export.widgets import ForeignKeyWidget


@admin.register(Post, Room, Classification, Person)
class TestappImportExport(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    pass

class Classificationresource(resources.ModelResource):
    name = fields.Field(
        column_name='name',
        attribute='name',
        widget=ForeignKeyWidget(Person, 'name'))

    room = fields.Field(
        column_name = 'room',
        attribute = 'room',
        widget= ForeignKeyWidget(Room, 'name'))

    class Meta:
        fields = ('name', 'room')
```

even I tried to reverse class Classificationresource(resources.ModelResource) up of Classificationresource(resources.ModelResource), and I still get ids and not the name of Persons or Rooms.

So please help me to solve this problem, I tired to stay searching and I feel that I spend a time for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#exporting):

> When defining ModelResource fields it is possible to follow model relationships:

```
class BookResource(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('author__name',)
```

So I'd try this:

```
class Classificationresource(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = Classification
        fields = ('id', 'name__name', 'room__name', 'date')
```

edit:
It is also necessary to add

```
@admin.register(Classification) 
class TestappImportExport(ImportExportModelAdmin): 
    resource_class = Classificationresource
```

Comment: I tried your solution , but it give the same result, when I export Data to Excel, I see ID's in Rows,

Comment: try this: 
@admin.register(Classification)
class TestappImportExport(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = Classificationresource

Comment: Great, I’ll update the answer to include this code.